# At what time is the speed minimum?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The position function of a particle is given by $r(t) = \langle-5t^2, -1t, t^2 + 1t\rangle$. At what time is the speed minimum?

Comment: Write an expression for the speed, then find the minima of that.  You need to show what you have done and where you are stuck...

Comment: I found the velocity vector = <-10t, -1, 2t + 1>. Then I got the magnitude as sqrt (104t^2 + 4t + 2). I know I need to minimize this magnitude, but I always get a negative t=-52

Comment: If $t < 0$ is allowed, the minimum must be at the *reciprocal* of what you got.

Comment: I get $t=-\frac{1}{52}$.

Answer (score 2):

The velocity vector is $\left<-10t,-1,2t+1\right>$. Thus the speed is $\sqrt{(-10t)^2 +(-1)^2+(2t+1)^2}$.

We want to minimize this, or equivalently we want to minimize $104t^2+4t+2$. This is a problem that can even be solved without calculus, by completing the square.

If negative $t$ is allowed, we get $t=-\frac{4}{208}$. If by nature $t\ge 0$, the minimum speed is at $t=0$.

Comment: When I minimized that function, I got t=-52, which is very misleading because time should be positive?

Comment: @Louise: You must have made a mistake...

Comment: You should get $t=-\frac{1}{52}$. There is nothing in the problem as stated that forces $t$ to be positive. But if somewhere else in the problem it is specified that $t\ge 0$, then the min is at $t=0$, since the function is increasing in the interval $(-1/52,\infty)$.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, it should be -1/52

Comment: The calculator police will be at your door.

Answer (score 1):

$$v(t)=r'(t)=<-10t,-1, 2t+1>$$
$$|v(t)|=\sqrt{100t^2+1+4t^2+4t+1}=\sqrt{104t^2+4t+1}$$
Now you want to minimize what's underneath the square root which we will call $f(t)$.

$$f'(t)=208t+4=0$$
Which gives $$t=\frac{-4}{208}=\frac{-1}{52}$$